# Как на PHP скрывать часть текста в зависимости от количества символов?

Tags: php

Как на PHP скрывать часть текста в зависимости от количества символов?

Звездочек должно быть всегда 8!

Если цифр 7 и больше, то отображать 3 первых и 3 последних

Если цифр 5 или 6, то отображать 2 первых и 2 последних

Если цифр 3 или 4, то отображать 1 первую и 1 последнюю

Если цифр 2, то отображать 1 первую

Если цифр 1, то отображать ее и отобразить

```
$key = "12345678901234567890";      // 123********890
$key = "1123456789012345678232190"; // 112********190
$key = "1145234140";                // 114********140
$key = "103482";                    // 10********82
$key = "534";                       // 5********4
$key = "28";                        // 2********
$key = "7";                         // 7
```

Еще возможно ее как то коротким кодом сделать, чтобы вставлять в любое место к коде?

Comment: Последний пример не соотв. правилу "Звездочек должно быть всегда 8!"

Comment: @Алексей, там просто скрывать нечего, нужно чтобы хотябы как минимум 1 цифра отображалась, для одного символа можно сделать исключение

Comment: Сами как-то пробовали решать?

Comment: Так и делать как у вас задано)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного улучшенная функция с if'ами

```
function hideNumber($string, $countFirstNumbersToShow = 1, $countLastNumbersToShow = 1, $countOfStars = 8) {
    return substr($string, 0, $countFirstNumbersToShow) . str_repeat('*', $countOfStars) . ($countLastNumbersToShow === 0 ? '' : substr($string, -$countLastNumbersToShow));
}

function someFunction($string) {
    $stringLength = strlen($string);
    
    if ($stringLength >= 7) {
        $newStr = hideNumber($string, 3, 3);
    } elseif ($stringLength >= 5) {
        $newStr = hideNumber($string, 2, 2);
    } elseif ($stringLength >= 3) {
        $newStr = hideNumber($string, 1, 1);
    } elseif ($stringLength == 2) {
        $newStr = hideNumber($string, 1, 0);
    } elseif ($stringLength == 1) {
        $newStr = hideNumber($string, 1, 0, 0);
    }
    
    return $newStr;
}
```

---

**UPD**  Функция `someFunction` с помощью **[match](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.match.php)** (появился в *PHP8*), а `hideNumber` без изменений

```
function someFunction($string) {
    $stringLength = strlen($string);
    
    return match (true) {
        $stringLength >= 7 => hideNumber($string, 3, 3),
        $stringLength >= 5 => hideNumber($string, 2, 2),
        $stringLength >= 3 => hideNumber($string, 1, 1),
        $stringLength === 2 => hideNumber($string, 1, 0),
        $stringLength === 1 => hideNumber($string, 1, 0, 0),
    };
}
```

Comment: switch мб впихнуть лучше7

Comment: и еще с `match` вариант тоже

Comment: @teran думал про switch. Но чёт особо разницы не вижу... а вот про match да, думаю неплохо...я уже забыл про него))

Comment: @teran добавил. красивенько))

Answer (score -1):

Как вариант, можно использовать данную функцию:

```
function YourNameFunction($str)
{
    $arr = str_split($str);
    $newstr = "";
    if(count($arr) >= 7) {
        $newstr = $arr[0].$arr[1].$arr[2]."********".$arr[count($arr) - 3].$arr[count($arr) - 2].$arr[count($arr) - 1];
    } elseif(count($arr) >= 5) {
        $newstr = $arr[0].$arr[1]."********".$arr[count($arr) - 2].$arr[count($arr) - 1];
    } elseif(count($arr) >= 3) {
        $newstr = $arr[0]."********".$arr[count($arr) - 1];
    } elseif(count($arr) == 2) {
        $newstr = $arr[0]."********";
    } elseif(count($arr) == 1) {
        $newstr = $arr[0];
    }
    return $newstr;
}
```

Так-же можно сократить код, чтобы убрать `$arr[count($arr) - 3]`

Вот более читабельная функция

```
function YourNameFunction($str)
{
    $arr = str_split($str);
    $newstr = "********";
    
    if(count($arr) > 2) {
        $n = 1;
        if(count($arr) >= 7) {
            $n = 3;
        } elseif(count($arr) >= 5) {
            $n = 2;
        }
        for($i = $n; $i > 0; i--) {
            $newstr = $arr[$i].$newstr.$arr[count($arr) - $i];
        }
    } elseif(count($arr) == 2) {
        $newstr = $arr[0].$newstr;
    } else {
        $newstr = $str;
    }
    return $newstr;
}
```

Comment: все будет гораздо проще, если использовать `substr`

Comment: "Вот более читабельная функция" --- нет

Comment: @teran в какой-то степени да, и то с помощью этого метода можно будет сократить for и дробление строки на массив символов

Comment: @АлексейШиманский предложите тогда свой, более читабельный  вариант

Comment: Первый вариант вполне читабельный... если вынести в переменную `count($arr)` и исплользовать её то совсем хорошо будет...... и вместо arr[0]/arr[1]/arr[2]  тоже читабельные переменные..... а второй вариант просто каша

Comment: @АлексейШиманский одна из главных задач в программировании - не дублировать код, в первом варианте - шло дублирование кода. Второй-же вариант убирает эту проблему, т.к. могут появится условия и что если 9-10 символов, 11-12 и т.д., тогда что делать? писать один и тот-же код и в случае какой ни будь правки - страдать?

Comment: "одна из главных задач в программировании - не дублировать код" --- не правда. ... нет таких задач у программирования и тем более в главных его аспектах.... а DRY нужно применять с умом........а  в DDD  так вообще порой бывает так, что **обязательно нужно дублировать** т.к. в ином случае  будут смешаны контексты никак с собой не связанные. Так что утверждение **полностью ошибочное** ...... но в то же время хорошо ли когда код не дублируется - да, хорошо, и неплохо бы избегать, но не обязательно и не является **задачей**

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1469201/191482 чуть доработал версию с if'ами. Стало красивее)   а ещё добавил с `match` и стало совсем прекрасно